# Radio button post data of multiple input fields

Tags: php, html, forms, post, radio-button

I have a form in my PHP page which is created by a loop through an array.

```
echo '<form method="POST" name="add_to_cart_form">
        <div id="Product_add_sizes">
           <table border="0" cellpadding="2" class="product_txt_font" align="center">
              <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="'.$arr_get_products[$c]['id'].'">';

                   for ($d = 0; $d < count($arr_get_product_details); $d++)
                   {
                      echo '<tr>
                              <td>
                                 <input type="radio" name="size[]" value="'.$arr_get_product_details[$d]['size'].'">
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                 <input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="amount" value="1">
                              </td>
                            </tr>';
                   }

     echo '</table>
          <input type="submit" name="add_to_chart" value="Add Product" />
        </div>
      </form>';
```

Now when I post this form, I'm searching for a way to get the input of qty which belongs to the selected radio button. I only need the data from the selected radio button row. The other data is not needed as I want to add this product to a shopping cart array.

```
if (isset($_POST['add_to_chart']))
{
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $size = $_POST['size'][0];
    $qty = $_POST['amount'];
}
```

When posting the page, I know what size is wanted cause of the `size[]`
 array but I can't get the related qty value that matches the selected radio button.

I've tried to treat the qty the same way as the radio button by making it an array `qty[]` but that will return me all values.

I've search SO and googled a bunch but haven't found a decent answer, but It looks to me that this is used a lot. Please let me know what i'm missing here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: name="size['.$d.']" will define the index it relates to, you also need to name="amount['.$d.']" on other input to match them up

Comment: $_POST['amount'] qty is the class!

Comment: Yea it was a type :) should be amount

Comment: @Fluffeh points out the real answer, it just that 'amount' was in the loop too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing the following.

The guys above here all got me on the right track and couldn't have done it without them!

Changed

```
<input type="radio" name="size[]" value="'.$arr_get_product_details[$d]['size'].'">
<input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="amount" value="1">
```

To

```
<input type="radio" name="size['.$d.']" value="'.$arr_get_product_details[$d]['size'].'">
<input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="amount['.$d.']" value="1">
```

Also changed

```
if (isset($_POST['add_to_chart']))
{
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $size = $_POST['size'][0];
    $qty = $_POST['amount'];
}
```

To this

```
if (isset($_POST['add_to_chart']))
{
    // Array ID key
    $key = key($_POST['size']);

    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $size = $_POST['size'][$key];
    $qty = $_POST['amount'][$key];
}
```

Works like a charm! Thank you all for your very helpful comments!

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons should all use the same name. Only the selected radio button value is submitted:

```
<input type="radio" name="Radiosize" value="'.$arr_get_product_details[$d]['size'].'">
```

then:

```
$size = $_POST['Radiosize'];
```

There is no need to look at it as an array - it isn't submitted as one. Radio Buttons are not like checkboxes in form processing.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="amount" value="1">
```

to

```
<input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="amount[]" value="1">
```

and then you will have 2 arrays that will have same size.

```
<?php
    $size = $_POST['size'][0];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'][$size];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Form code:

```
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="'.$arr_get_product_details[$d]['size'].'">
    <input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="amount['.$arr_get_product_details[$d]['size'].']" value="1">
```

And then you will have value of size. And array of amounts with size keys.

```
    $size   = $_POST['size'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'][$size];
```