# Have a 3 radio buttons for each row PHP

Tags: php, html

Im creating a web app and one of the features is for truck checks. It lists all the checks in a table with a pass, warning, and fail option as radio buttons. How do you make each radio button unique inside of a while loop? And how do you post the values for each check radio button on form submit?

[Click to see what my web app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hHzc.png)

This is my table's code:

```
<div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
             
<h2 align="center"><?php echo $appname?></h2><br />
<div class="form-group">

<form name="add_name" id="add_name">                    
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
         <?php while ($checks = mysqli_fetch_array($checksqry)) {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'.$checks['check_name']. '</td>' ;
         echo '<td> 
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnpasss" id="btnpass" value="Pass">
            <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-success" for="btnpass">Pass</label>&Tab;&Tab;
                    
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnwarning" id="btnwarning" value="Warning">
            <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-warning" for="btnwarning">Warning</label>&Tab;&Tab;
                    
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnfail" id="btnfail" value="Fail">
            <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-danger" for="btnfail">Fail</label>&Tab;&Tab;
                    
           <button type="button" name="comment" id="comment" class="btn btn-info"><img src="assets/comment.png" width="20px"></button> </td>';
        echo '<tr>';}?>
      </table>
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
   </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create an index for each row and use it for the radio. Maybe you can use that from your query.

Comment: Why don't your radio buttons share the same `name` (like normal sets of radio buttons)?

Comment: Wow, there are a shocking amount of duplicates that I could not use because they were not naming the buttons with square brace syntax!  When you implement https://stackoverflow.com/a/54913057/2943403 be sure to give the same counter/id to all other fields in the row.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43284414/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/55135186/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44821393/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57920015/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12004648/2943403

Comment: Even with the square bracket syntax for the button name, its still acting as one button for the entire form.  name="btnpasss[ ' . $checks['check_name'] . ' ] "

Comment: But your `$checks['check_name']` is unique per row, is it not? There are no duplicates of it, across the whole table? What do the name attributes of the radio buttons in two different rows now actually look like, when you check the generated HTML / inspect the DOM?

Comment: Yes, they do have separate, unique names in the dev tools. But If i click pass on a check down the list, it marks the first check as pass. It acts as if it has the same name, but it doesnt.

Comment: I fixed it with the help from the above comments. If anyone else is having a similar issue, you have to also change your input id and label for attribute.  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Pass">
     <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-success" for="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Pass</label>

Comment: please don't add solutions inside a question

Comment: Glad you fixed it...but: The answer is not part of the question! Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. I've rolled back the edit to your question. Since your post is closed as a duplicate of another you can't add an Answer formally, so your options are: 1) add a relevant answer to the duplicate, if your situation is a variation on the same scenario, or 2) make the case (by editing it) for why your question _isn't_ a duplicate of that one, then people might vote to re-open it, at which point you could add an answer here. Thanks